# Custom locator not matching to entry with best score using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, geocoding, address

I created a custom locator using the **Create Locator** tool to create individual county geocoders, then used the **Create Composite Address Locator** to combine them. When I geocoded a CSV file,  I had about 19% that were "Tied".

[image]

As I started using the **Rematch Address** tool to fix them, I noticed that there was actually a 100% match for most of them, but Arc defaulted to the one with the worst score.

Example:

[image]

*Of those that were "Tied", Arc automatically displayed the points with a 60% match even though there is a 100% match.*

When I tried looking for a solution in help, all I found was that it should've matched to the best score.

[image]

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geocoding/tips-for-improving-geocoding-quality.htm

Seeing how there are over 86,000 instances of this, I'd prefer not to go through every entry to correct. Is there a way to just rematch all of them to the best score?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the result order. The default is to use the order the different locators within the composite locator: [https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/data/geocoding/tips-for-tuning-composite-locators.htm#:~:text=If%20you%20create%20a%20composite,then%20use%20the%20custom%20locator](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/data/geocoding/tips-for-tuning-composite-locators.htm#:%7E:text=If%20you%20create%20a%20composite,then%20use%20the%20custom%20locator). If your first locator has a match is above the minimum match score, it will chose that one even if the matches that follow have better scores.

Note: **The result order must be set prior to publishing the locator and must be republished to adjust the order after it has already been published**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).